# SQL Listagg as extra column

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'm looking for an Oracle SQL query that is aggregating a column, but adds the aggregation as an extra column, instead of 'really' aggregating the rows. So I want to end up with exact the same number of rows, with an extra column with the aggregated values. A sample below should help to show what I mean.

Starting table:

```
ID    GIVEN_NAME   LAST_NAME
11    CARL         CLARKE
22    CARL         CLARKE
33    CARL         CLARKE
44    ANDREW       JOHNSON
55    ANDREW       JOHNSON
```

A regular listagg(ID) group by GIVEN_NAME and LAST_NAME would give me:

```
LISTAGG(ID)   GIVEN_NAME   LAST_NAME
112233        CARL         CLARKE
4455          ANDREW       JOHNSON
```

What I want is just adding an aggregate column:

```
AGGREGATE   ID    GIVEN_NAME   LAST_NAME
112233      11    CARL         CLARKE
112233      22    CARL         CLARKE
112233      33    CARL         CLARKE
4455        44    ANDREW       JOHNSON
4455        55    ANDREW       JOHNSON
```

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use LISTAGG function in [analytic form](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) (OVER (analytic clause)):

```
select GIVEN_NAME, LAST_NAME,
    LISTAGG(ID) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) as "AGGREGATE"
  from SOMETABLE
```

See also [Analytic example in LISTAGG documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466)

Answer (score 0):

here is one option for you, using listagg:

```
with sample_data as (
    select level     id,level given_name,level last_name from dual connect by level <= 10
    union all
    select level+30  id,level given_name,level last_name from dual connect by level <= 5
    union all
    select level+500 id,level given_name,level last_name from dual connect by level <= 3
    order by id
)
select 
    (select listagg(id) within group (order by id) 
     from sample_data di 
     where di.given_name=d.given_name and di.last_name=d.last_name) aggregate
    ,d.* 
    from sample_data d
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The are two options of [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) aggregated and analytic.

You are seeking the analytic option:

**Agregate function**

```
select name, listagg(id) within group (order by id)  as lst
from tab
group by name;

NAME LST 
---- ------
X    1112   
Y    1314
```

**Analytic function**

Note that `OVER` clause, that using the `PARTITION BY` represents the grouping key.

```
select name, id, listagg(id) within group (order by id) over( partition by name)  as lst
from tab;


NAME         ID LST  
---- ---------- -------
X            11 1112    
X            12 1112    
Y            13 1314     
Y            14 1314
```

Answer (score 0):

this will  work:

```
create table table123(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20),col3 varchar(20)) 
insert into table123 values('11' ,   'CARL'   ,      'CLARKE');
insert into table123 values('22'  ,  'CARL'    ,     'CLARKE');
insert into table123 values('33'  ,  'CARL'    ,    'CLARKE');
insert into table123 values('44'  ,  'ANDREW'  ,     'JOHNSON');
insert into table123 values('55'  ,  'ANDREW'  ,     'JOHNSON');
SELECT * FROM table123;

SELECT a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,(select LISTAGG(col1, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
col2) "aggreaget" from table123 where col2=a.col2 group by col2 ) 
FROM table123 a group by a.col2,a.col1,a.col3 order by a.col1
```

sample output:

```
11  CARL    CLARKE  112233
22  CARL    CLARKE  112233
33  CARL    CLARKE  112233
44  ANDREW  JOHNSON 4455
55  ANDREW  JOHNSON 4455
```